# How to use uninitialized static array in C++?

Tags: c++, static

Okay, here is my C++ header file:

```
// a.h

class A
{
private:
    static A* aContainer[10];

public:
    static void generate(int amount);

}
```

And here's `.cpp` file:

```
// a.cpp

void A::generate(int amount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        aContainer[i] = new Container();
    } 
}
```

I know `static` fields must be initialized but I need ability to have some specific amount of elements in `aContainer`. If I initialize `aContainer` it will contain all 10 elements but 10 meant to be the maximum number of elements.

Can I initialize `aContainer` with `NULL`s or something like that?

Comment: use `std::vector` or `std::deque` for variable size container

Comment: As a static member of a class, the array is automatically initialized with null pointers. I also recommend using a real container, and also consider `std::unique_ptr` so that the objects are destroyed at the end of day.

Comment: Static vars in a class/struct do not create any memory.  You need to declare them at global scope as well to get memory for them.

Comment: @BryanChen way to be but I know I need up to 10 elements only so I don't really need to use `std::vector`. I just don't want all 10 elements to be created at initialization. I need an empty `aContainer`.

Comment: With a vector you can get bounds checking, and you can resize it so might not need to use pointers anymore, so it's harder to leak memory.

Comment: So you need something with a known capacity but variable size. I give you ... `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you have a good reason for not using `std::vector` which is the natural way to solve this problem.

An array or struct can be initialized with braces:

```
    A* A::aContainer[10] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

If any members aren't listed, they're initialized with zero. So the above can be simplified:

```
    A* A::aContainer[10] = {};
```

Comment: It can be simplified further to `A* A::aContainer[];`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @NeilKirk are statics guaranteed by the standard to be initialized to zero? I know that in practice they often are, but I didn't think it was guaranteed.

Comment: It is for basic data types I thought.

Comment: @MarkRansom variables of static storage duration are initialized as if by `= {};` if there is no initializer